# Transpose midi with Drywetmidi

Tags: c#, .net, midi

can you tell me how to change the key of all notes of a midi file during playback. I tried with this code but nothing happens.

on click i write
midiFile.ProcessNotes(n => n.NoteNumber -= (SevenBitNumber)1,);
one semitone less or
midiFile.ProcessNotes(n => n.NoteNumber += (SevenBitNumber)1,);
one semitone more.

but not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of DryWetMIDI. You're talking about playback, but showing `midiFile.ProcessNotes`. So what do you want to achieve?

If you want to transpose notes **during playback** use `NoteCallback` property. You can see example of usage in the documentation – https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia.Playback.html#Melanchall_DryWetMidi_Multimedia_Playback_NoteCallback.

When you get `Playback` object (via `midiFile.GetPlayback()` for example), the playback is detached from MIDI file. So there is no any sense to modify the file since those modifications won't be reflected in the `Playback`.

If you want something different, modify your post and provide as many details as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed.
Since I use notecallback to mute tracks,
Now I just have to find a way to do both.